# Problem using JSON.as

Tags: json, actionscript-2

#### My code

```
 import JSON;

 var j = "{fef:34}";
 var json = new JSON();
 trace(json.parse(j));   // undefined !!!
```

It doesn't work; the trace will return undefined. I'm compiling for Flash 8 in ActionScript 2. The file `JSON.as` is in the same folder (see below).

When debugging it says value for `json` after `json = new JSON()` is undefined.

#### JSON.as (from JSON.org)

```
class JSON {
            var ch:String = '';
            var at:Number = 0;
            var t,u;
            var text:String;

    function stringify(arg):String {

        var c, i, l, s = '', v;

        switch (typeof arg) {
        case 'object':
            if (arg) {
                if (arg instanceof Array) {
                    for (i = 0; i < arg.length; ++i) {
                        v = stringify(arg[i]);
                        if (s) {
                            s += ',';
                        }
                        s += v;
                    }
                    return '[' + s + ']';
                } else if (typeof arg.toString != 'undefined') {
                    for (i in arg) {
                        v = arg[i];
                        if (typeof v != 'undefined' && typeof v != 'function') {
                            v = stringify(v);
                            if (s) {
                                s += ',';
                            }
                            s += stringify(i) + ':' + v;
                        }
                    }
                    return '{' + s + '}';
                }
            }
            return 'null';
        case 'number':
            return isFinite(arg) ? String(arg) : 'null';
        case 'string':
            l = arg.length;
            s = '"';
            for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
                c = arg.charAt(i);
                if (c >= ' ') {
                    if (c == '\\' || c == '"') {
                        s += '\\';
                    }
                    s += c;
                } else {
                    switch (c) {
                        case '\b':
                            s += '\\b';
                            break;
                        case '\f':
                            s += '\\f';
                            break;
                        case '\n':
                            s += '\\n';
                            break;
                        case '\r':
                            s += '\\r';
                            break;
                        case '\t':
                            s += '\\t';
                            break;
                        default:
                            c = c.charCodeAt();
                            s += '\\u00' + Math.floor(c / 16).toString(16) +
                                (c % 16).toString(16);
                    }
                }
            }
            return s + '"';
        case 'boolean':
            return String(arg);
        default:
            return 'null';
        }
    }
        function white() {
            while (ch) {
                if (ch <= ' ') {
                    this.next();
                } else if (ch == '/') {
                    switch (this.next()) {
                        case '/':
                            while (this.next() && ch != '\n' && ch != '\r') {}
                            break;
                        case '*':
                            this.next();
                            for (;;) {
                                if (ch) {
                                    if (ch == '*') {
                                        if (this.next() == '/') {
                                            next();
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        this.next();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    error("Unterminated comment");
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            this.error("Syntax error");
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        function error(m) {
            throw {
                name: 'JSONError',
                message: m,
                at: at - 1,
                text: text
            };
        }
        function next() {
            ch = text.charAt(at);
            at += 1;
            return ch;
        }
        function str() {
            var i, s = '', t, u;
            var outer:Boolean = false;

            if (ch == '"') {
                while (this.next()) {
                    if (ch == '"') {
                        this.next();
                        return s;
                    } else if (ch == '\\') {
                        switch (this.next()) {
                        case 'b':
                            s += '\b';
                            break;
                        case 'f':
                            s += '\f';
                            break;
                        case 'n':
                            s += '\n';
                            break;
                        case 'r':
                            s += '\r';
                            break;
                        case 't':
                            s += '\t';
                            break;
                        case 'u':
                            u = 0;
                            for (i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
                                t = parseInt(this.next(), 16);
                                if (!isFinite(t)) {
                                    outer = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                                u = u * 16 + t;
                            }
                            if(outer) {
                                outer = false;
                                break;
                            }
                            s += String.fromCharCode(u);
                            break;
                        default:
                            s += ch;
                        }
                    } else {
                        s += ch;
                    }
                }
            }
            this.error("Bad string");
        }

        function arr() {
            var a = [];

            if (ch == '[') {
                this.next();
                this.white();
                if (ch == ']') {
                    this.next();
                    return a;
                }
                while (ch) {
                    a.push(this.value());
                    this.white();
                    if (ch == ']') {
                        this.next();
                        return a;
                    } else if (ch != ',') {
                        break;
                    }
                    this.next();
                    this.white();
                }
            }
            this.error("Bad array");
        }

        function obj() {
            var k, o = {};

            if (ch == '{') {
                this.next();
                this.white();
                if (ch == '}') {
                    this.next();
                    return o;
                }
                while (ch) {
                    k = this.str();
                    this.white();
                    if (ch != ':') {
                        break;
                    }
                    this.next();
                    o[k] = this.value();
                    this.white();
                    if (ch == '}') {
                        this.next();
                        return o;
                    } else if (ch != ',') {
                        break;
                    }
                    this.next();
                    this.white();
                }
            }
            this.error("Bad object");
        }

        function num() {
            var n = '', v;

            if (ch == '-') {
                n = '-';
                this.next();
            }
            while (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
                n += ch;
                this.next();
            }
            if (ch == '.') {
                n += '.';
                this.next();
                while (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
                    n += ch;
                    this.next();
                }
            }
            if (ch == 'e' || ch == 'E') {
                n += ch;
                this.next();
                if (ch == '-' || ch == '+') {
                    n += ch;
                    this.next();
                }
                while (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
                    n += ch;
                    this.next();
                }
            }
            v = Number(n);
            if (!isFinite(v)) {
                this.error("Bad number");
            }
            return v;
        }

        function word() {
            switch (ch) {
                case 't':
                    if (this.next() == 'r' && this.next() == 'u' &&
                            this.next() == 'e') {
                        this.next();
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    if (this.next() == 'a' && this.next() == 'l' &&
                            this.next() == 's' && this.next() == 'e') {
                        this.next();
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    if (this.next() == 'u' && this.next() == 'l' &&
                            this.next() == 'l') {
                        this.next();
                        return null;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            this.error("Syntax error");
        }

        function value() {
            this.white();
            switch (ch) {
                case '{':
                    return this.obj();
                case '[':
                    return this.arr();
                case '"':
                    return this.str();
                case '-':
                    return this.num();
                default:
                    return ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' ? this.num() : this.word();
            }
        }
    function parse(_text:String):Object {
        text = _text;
            at = 0;
        ch = ' ';
        return value();
    }
}
```

Why is `json` undefined at the end of my code?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your file name is **JSON.as** with upper case.

if you write `import JSON;` and your file name is json.as you will get undefined!

```
> Blockquote
import JSON;

var json = new JSON();

trace(json);

// Output:

[object Object]

    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Debugging line by line I found this line has a problem
but I don't know why :

```
s += '\\u00' + Math.floor(c / 16).toString(16) + (c % 16).toString(16);
```

Answer (score 0):

The class only work if you publish as ActionScript 2.
Also the if JSON.as isn't in the same directory as the fla, you will need to specify the path e.g. import com.JSON;